# Public information quality trends vs quantity

Tags: data-quality

With the great increase of publically viewable information (content) supported by the internet and modern communications, is the average quality of that information decreasing, roughly static, or increasing?

To put some bounds on that, let's constrain that to human accessible information, and let's weight it in terms of views by persons of the respective content on whatever medium. Clearly, we have vastly more information, but its visibility is uneven.

Put another way, do we know for sure how public information quality has trended, on average, since the pre-internet era?

This is likely to vary by subject domain. I see there are academic studies in some areas, e.g. particularly about medical information, but cannot determine if this is even being measured or studied in a wider sense. Clearly, the answer has numerous implications for the digital world and public policy, among others.

[Here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/fullHtml/10.1145/3018809) is one perspective, but it's not quantitative and somewhat narrow in scope.